# remove black diamond with a question mark text from android sdcard file

Tags: java, android, json, listview, special-characters

I am creating a listview with json data.When user is offline I want to show the data in listview. I have stored the json data in android sdcard. And I retrive the data when user is offline and showed it in listview. The problem is, when I read the file from directory it's show's me black diamond with a question mark and stores it in array list. this type of "����t��*" my question is how to remove this type of string from Arraylist. Someone please help

Save the Data:

```
 public  void saveMyData()
{
    try {
        ObjectOutput out = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(new File(getFilesDir(),"")+"cachefile.txt"));
        out.writeObject(al.toString());
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Data Saved..",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        out.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

This is my retrieving code.

```
String fileContent = "";
    try {
        String currentLine;
        BufferedReader bufferedReader;
        FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(getFilesDir()+"cachefile.txt");
        bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fileInputStream,"UTF-8"));


        while ((currentLine = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            fileContent += currentLine + '\n';
        }

        bufferedReader.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

        Log.d("FAILED","THOS IS NULL");
        fileContent = null;
    }
    Log.d("SUCESS","SUCESS BUDDYY"+fileContent);
```

Comment: can you also share how you are saving the data? it sounds like you have an encoding mismatch between how you're saving it and how you're retrieving it.

Comment: See updated question

Answer (score 1):

Broadly speaking, the issue is that you're using an `ObjectOutputStream` to write your data to the file, but a `BufferedReader` to read it back in. The `ObjectOutputStream` is specifically designed to allow objects and native data types to be written to a stream in a way they can be read back in via an `ObjectInputStream` to reconstitute the objects in the same way. This encoding is not meant to be human readable and usually contains extra characters as field separators.

I don't know what `al` is, but since you're calling `toString()` before you write it, I can assume that you want actual strings in a file you can read. To do this, you probably want to use a [`PrintStream`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/PrintStream.html) and the [`PrintStream.println()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/PrintStream.html#println(java.lang.String)) method instead of the `ObjectOutputStream`.